# Flutter Error drawRenderNode called on a context with no surface

Tags: flutter

I don't see the error on the emulator, but the production google play console under Crashes and ARNs shows the error: drawRenderNode called on a context with no surface!

I am running the latest version of Flutter and Dart and Android studio.
I am developing the app on windows 11.

This error does not occur on all devices.

The error details:

```
The device: TECNO TECNO-KG5k

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000004e178  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000552e3c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2260)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000013990  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000006e58  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+336)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000215568  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::getFrame()+52)
  #05  pc 0x000000000021e4b8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+404)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000220ac8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+496)
  #07  pc 0x000000000020f2ec  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+220)
  #08  pc 0x00000000002302f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+88)
  #09  pc 0x0000000000015414  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+260)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000014cd8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+412)
  #11  pc 0x00000000000af97c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #12  pc 0x00000000000500d0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

Could you please help to figure out what's going on.

Thank You